# What's the difference between OAuthAccessTokenException and APIRequiresAuthenticationError in Instagram's API?

Tags: instagram

I've got two completely different errors coming back in my logs for requests to the same endpoint:

`GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self.json?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]`

Sometimes it's this:

`{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}`

And other times it's this:

`{"meta":{"error_type":"APIRequiresAuthenticationError","code":400,"error_message":"'self' keyword requires an authenticated user"}}`

One of them is clearly an invalid token that needs to be refreshed, but I can't figure out what the other could mean.  I'm trying to determine if this is an error that I can have a user recover from (like by having them refresh their token), or if it's something more serious, like maybe they deleted their account.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you get the `APIRequiresAuthenticationError` when a user has deleted his/her account.  There may be other ways to get the error as well, but this is at least one scenario where this error type is returned.